# Vertical scrollbar doesn't appear in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with a web application which works well in IE8 but not in IE11.
One of the issues is that vertical scrollbar doesn't appear in IE11.
The compatibility mode isn't an option.

I tried with this but it didn't work.

```
-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
```

My css looks actually like this:

```
.tableform .content {
    padding:            8px;
    overflow:           auto;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
}
```

Scrollbar works in IE8 with `overflow: auto;` but not in IE11.

Please help.

Comment: It could be a problem with your percentage height. To debug, try changing `height:100%` to `height:5000px` and see if the scrollbar shows up.

Comment: You should post a jsfiddle of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a jsfiddle to see what your actual code is there's not a lot we can do, but in this test:

http://jsfiddle.net/3g5pqdf8/

```
<div class="tableform">HI!</div>

.tableform {
    padding:            8px;
    overflow:           auto;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

My div's actual height is only as big as its content, and the overflow: auto cuts it off.

Whereas with a minor edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/3g5pqdf8/2/

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}
.tableform {
    padding:            8px;
    width:              100%;
    height:             100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I get the scrollbar back.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for the question but I couldn't find the solution till now.

Comment: It's not a problem, but you got lucky: not a lot of angry stack elitists lit into you about it. Familiarize yourself with [the how to ask questions guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll have a good experience here.